# Decipher preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to fix some code written by another developer:

```
 $rexSafety = '@[0-9-\+\s\(\)]+$@';
 if (!preg_match($rexSafety, $_POST['phone'])) $spam = true;
```

When I type in an 11-digit number (UK standard phone length) without spaces or any other characters, the number (from `$_POST['phone']`) is marked as spam.

Unfortunately I don't know anything about regular expressions so I was hoping someone would be able to 'decipher' this and tell me what it is expecting?

`01234567890` should be a match. It's currently not.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

It's a great site to understand regexp

Comment: Please add an example of UK telephone number that doesnt matches the regexp and one number that instead matches.

Comment: Hi @Bolza - 01234567890 should be a match. It's currently not (according to the site code I'm trying to fix, and Med's link to regex101.com). I don't know what does match - that is my question. What is this regex trying to match? What would make it succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the breakdown of your regex. I threw out the `@` because he used those as boundary characters. Normally you would use something like `/` instead (note that's what [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) uses)

```
[0-9-\+\s\(\)]+$
```

`[]` indicates a character set we want to match. You put everything you want matched in here. A dash means you have a range so `0-9` will match all decimal numbers

`\` is the escape character. It means you want literal characters. So `\+` is going to match `+` in your string

`\s` is a special class that matches whitespace

`\(\)` means you want to match any parenthesis `(` or `)`

`$` is the end of your string (this is unnecessary since we want anything that matches)

I tweaked it and this should do what you want

```
if(preg_match('/([^0-9-\+\s\(\)])/', $_POST['phone'])) $spam = true;
```

By adding `^` we tell regex we **don't** want anything from this class to match. I also wrapped it in parenthesis to make it a capturing group. That means it will grab the matching elements and return them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check 11 digits, it's `\d{11}`

```
 $rexSafety = '~^\d{11}$~';
 if (!preg_match($rexSafety, $_POST['phone'])) $spam = true;
```

If the format with spaces, dashes, etc. is valid (don't know british phone numbers), first remove these characters to get plain number.

```
$phone = str_replace(array(' ', '-'), '', $_POST['phone']); // remove spaces & dashes
$rexSafety = '~^\d{11}$~';
if (!preg_match($rexSafety, $phone)) $spam = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Panther. Do you know what the regex in the original question is actually trying to match though? Can you decipher it? As I said, I am trying to fix someone else's code and I don't know what this regex is trying to match - all I know is it's failing!

Comment: Take everything what ends by at least one of these characters: `number, -, +, space/tab/new line, (, )`. Nothing about beginning, eg. `abc12(+1` should be valid because it ends by allowed characters.